# Scrape a website that loads table based on dynamically selected dropdown values

Tags: python, python-requests, scrape

I am trying to scrape table values from [this website.](https://election.gov.np/np/page/voter-list-db). There are multiple dropdown which change based on selections in the previous dropdown. Upon inspecting the source, it seems to sending HTTP requests and render the results. However, I can't seem to write script to send those requests myself and scrape the data.

This is what I tried:

```
import requests

URL = 'https://voterlist.election.gov.np/bbvrs1/index_process_1.php' #API URL
payload = 'vdc=5298&ward=1&list_type=reg_centre' #Unique payload fetched from the network request
response = requests.post(URL,data=payload,verify=False) #POST request to get the data using URL and Payload information
print(response.text)
```

This is not giving me the expected response which should be a table containing the values. What could be the best approach to take in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few hours of digging in I found an answer. All I had to do was send a cookie while making the request and also change the format the payload was sent in.

```
headers = {
     
    'num': number, # This the cookie that should be sent which happens to be a session id in my case. 
}

payload = {
    'state': "1",
    "district": "14",
    "vdc_mun": "5132",
    "ward": "3",
    "reg_centre" :"" 
    
}
#Then send a post request to the url
res = session.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)
```